# Remove git commit without changing current file contents

Tags: git, github

I did two commits on a project. In the first commit, I forgot to add a dir full of data to my .gitignore. This dir contains more than 2Gb of data. I added this dir to my .gitignore and removed it from git with git rm -r -cached DirName . I then commited a second time. I would like to push this to gitHub but they have a maximum size of 2Gb. How can i remove this commit without effecting the current project.

Below is my git log for the last two commits

```
$ git log -2
commit 289a05f08d6bfb3a7a40622896e3f941d459c832 (HEAD -> master)
Author: XX
Date:   Mon Jan 15 11:17:26 2024 +0000

    Remove datasets dir from git

commit dd65c5033bbc999994dc3aa3add756f1488416db
Author: XX
Date:   Sun Jan 14 22:14:06 2024 +0000

    Centralized model, Squeezenet weights, Seperate Images
```

Edit: This is not the same as the other answers marked as similar as there was another commit after the large file.

Comment: What did you do in your second commit? it might be relevant for the solution, especially if you tried to fix the problem caused in the first commit.

Comment: My second commit i made a couple of changes to the code and removed the datasets dir from git. I changed .gitignore as well

Comment: The simplest way, if you are on top of the second commit is to do a soft reset to the previous commit and commit/amend there: `git reset --soft HEAD~; git commit --amend --no-edit`. Now you have a single commit with the right content. Now, next time you realized that you _missied_ something from the last commit, just add the missing changes you want to have in the commit to the index and do `git commit --amend --no-edit`.

Comment: You should have amended your latest commit instead of creating a new commit. But you can still squash your two commits now into a single commit, which will effectively remove the files/directory from your history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can undo both commits without changing your local files with.

```
git reset HEAD~2
```

This will move your HEAD back two commits and will clear the index.
Then you have to add the .gitignore changes to the index.

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m"Ignore data directory"
```

Then you should be able to add all your other stuff to the index without any problems.

```
git add .
git commit
git push
```